# Powershell - performance issues using out-file in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, file, export

The following scripts converts an XML into a specific CSV format to feed a specific source system.
It works fine, but the performance is incredibly slow. I believe the issue is because Out-File is opening - closing the file for every line. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$url = 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml'
$result = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url
$elements = $result.Envelope.Cube

foreach($element in $elements)
{
    foreach($x in $element.Cube)
    {
        foreach($y in $x.Cube)
        {
            $time = $x.time.ToString() -replace "-"
            $output =  $time + "`t" + $y.currency.ToString() + "`t" + $y.rate.ToString()
            $output | Out-File -Append ".\rates.csv"
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe the issue is because Out-File is opening - closing the file for every line

That is indeed the reason, so **the key to speeding up your command is to pipe all data to a *single* invocation of `Out-File`**, which you can achieve by wrapping your `foreach` loop in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) that you invoke with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```sh
& {
  foreach ($element in $elements) {
    foreach ($x in $element.Cube) {
      foreach ($y in $x.Cube) {
        $time = $x.time.ToString() -replace "-"
        # Synthesize and output the line to save.
        $time + "`t" + $y.currency.ToString() + "`t" + $y.rate.ToString()
      }
    }   
  }
} | Out-File .\rates.csv
```

The above preserves PowerShell's typical *streaming* pipeline behavior, sending output lines *one by one* to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file).

Given that your data is already *in memory* anyway, you can speed up the operation a little by using `$(...)` rather than `& { ... }` around your `foreach` loop, i.e. by using `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).

---

That said, ***in-memory* data allows even faster processing**:

- Through bypassing the *pipeline* and instead passing all output lines as an *argument*.
- Additionally, given that you're saving *text* to a file, by using [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) to speed things up a bit.

  - Note: In *Windows PowerShell*, `Set-Content`'s default encoding differs from `Out-File`'s: the active ANSI code page's encoding vs. UTF-16LE ("Unicode"); in *PowerShell [Core] 7+*, all cmdlets consistently default to BOM-less UTF-8; use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.
- Finally, you can eliminate one level of nesting from your `foreach` loops by taking advantage of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

```sh
# Adjust -Encoding as needed.
Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\rates.csv -Value $(
  foreach ($x in $elements.Cube) {
    foreach ($y in $x.Cube) {
      $time = $x.time.ToString() -replace "-"
      # Synthesize and output the output line.
      $time + "`t" + $y.currency.ToString() + "`t" + $y.rate.ToString()
    }
  }   
)
```

Comment: the last one is the fastest method - i'm now down to 1.2 seconds! 
thanks a lot for the extensive explanation, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml'
$result = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url
$elements = $result.Envelope.Cube

$outputAll = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

foreach($element in $elements)
{
    foreach($x in $element.Cube)
    {
        foreach($y in $x.Cube)
        {
            $time = $x.time.ToString() -replace "-"
            $output =  $time + "`t" + $y.currency.ToString() + "`t" + $y.rate.ToString()
            $null = $outputAll.add($output)
        }
    }   
}

$outputAll | Out-File -Append ".\rates.csv"
```

Comment: works like a charm, takes 4 seconds vs 5 minutes before! thanks

Comment: I would like to add that the reason for this is that `Out-File` is an cmdlet that involves IO operations. These are generally very expensive, and should be used as little as possible. As you have found, collecting the result first and then calling `Out-File` once speeds things up considerably.